# Dynamic font size with iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am doing a chat application. I have implement all views using frame. Now i need to implement dynamic font size i.e app should be resize its frame with respect to font in settings. If some one have any idea about that then please help me out ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A proper use of Size classes and Auto Shrink property will get you through.

You'll get the best explanation [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)

Comment: In application, There is no use of xib or storyboard. We inflate the view using frames like UIView *view  = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame]. We also doing same for UITableView and UITableViewCells. If u have provide me some solution using frame that would be great help from your side. Because i am not able to do without using the storyboard. But in our app , all ui related part is inflating using the frame. So i need a solution for the same.Thanks.